# Theoretical Drying capacity of CaSO4

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

What is the Theoretical Drying capacity of CaSO4 when used to dry solvents? e.g. How much water can 1 gm of CaSO4 remove?

Now since CaSO4 itself comes in several forms (anhydrous, hemihydrate, dihydrate) I am wondering which is the form best suited for water absorption?

If I assume that the drying transition is from CaSO4 (anhydr.) to CaSO4.2H2O (dihydrate) then I get a drying capacity of approx. 0.26 gm H2O per gm CaSO4 used.

Is this the right capacity? Or am I using an incorrect reaction?

Answer (score 3):

The actual drying agent is calcium sulfate semihydrate. It has low drying capacity, which decreases already after the uptake of $6.6\%$ water (theoretical maximum is $15.7\%$). Within these limits, however, it is possible, for example, to dry air at room temperature down to $0.0004\ mg$ of water per liter of air. It is suitable for drying almost all liquids and gases. It can be regenerated by heating to $190-230^{\circ}C$. Above $300^{\circ}C$ it loses its drying properties. The data comes from an old Merck's handbook on drying agents.

Comment: Thanks! Is the "semihydrate" the same as the "hemihydrate"? i.e. CaSO4.0.5H2O?

Comment: @curious_cat Yes, those are the same.